# Light shader moved while resizing window

Tags: c++, glsl, sfml

I've been working around to make a little light shader.
It works perfectly, I mean, the light fades as it's supposed to, it's a circle around my character moving with it.
It could be perfect only if that resizing event wasn't existing.

When SFML resizes the window, it enlarges everything, but in a strange way. It enlarged everything **but shaders**.
I tried to resize my window (I love resizing pixel graph games, I find it most beautiful. So I don't want to prevent the resizing event).

Here's my shader :

```
    uniform vec3 light;

void main(void) {
    float distance = sqrt(pow(gl_FragCoord.x - light.x, 2) + pow(gl_FragCoord.y - light.y, 2));
    float alpha = 1.;

    if (distance <= light.z) {
        alpha = (1.0 / light.z) * distance;
    }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0., 0., 0., alpha);

}
```

So, the problem is, my window is showed at 1280 x 736 (to fit with 32x32 textures), and I have a 1920 x 1080 monitor. When I enlarge the window to fit in 1920 x 1080 (title bar included), the whole thing resizes correctly, everything's fine, but the shader is now 1920x1080 (minus the title bar). So the shader needs different coordinates (what's supposed to be in x = 32, y = 0 is, for the shader, in x = 48 y = 0).

So I was wondering, is it possible to enlarge the shader with the whole window ? Should I use events or something like that ?

Thanks for your answers ^^

EDIT : Here's some pics :
[image: Before]
So this is the light shader before it resizes (it's dark everywhere but on the player, like it's supposed to be).
[image: After]Then I resize the window, the player doesn't move, the textures fit the entire window, but the light moved.

So, to explain correctly, when I resize the window, I want everything to fit the window, so it's full of textures, but when I do that, the coordinates given to my shader are the ones before resizing, and if I move it moves as if I didn't resize the window, so the light is never on my player again.

I'm not sure it's clearer, but I tried my best.

EDIT2 : Here's my code which calls the shader :

```
void Graphics::UpdateLight() {
    short radius = 65; // 265 on the pictures

    int x = m_game->GetPlayer()->GetSprite()->getPosition().x + CASE_LEN / 2; // Setting on the middle of the player sprite (CASE_LEN is a const which contains the size of a case (here 32))
    int y = HEIGHT - (m_game->GetPlayer()->GetSprite()->getPosition().y + CASE_LEN / 2); // (the "HEIGHT -" part was set because it seems that y = 0 is on the bottom of the texture for GLSL)

    sf::Vector3f shaderLight;
    shaderLight.x = x;
    shaderLight.y = y;
    shaderLight.z = radius;

    m_lightShader.setParameter("light", shaderLight);
}
```

Comment: I found your explanation difficult to understand. However, it is clear that it doesn't scale well because you are using window coordinates (gl_FragCoord) instead of normalized devices coordinates or other kind of coordinates that don't depend on the window resolution. You can take the NDC from the vertex shader or divide gl_FragCoord by the window resolution (taking it from an uniform variable)

Comment: What part didn't you understand ? I can try to clarify it ^^'
Well, I don't use vertex shader, I only use frag shader (I'm very new to glsl, sorry :c)

Comment: I don't clearly understand what are you trying to do, is this pixel art? can you provide a picture? how do want exactly to handle different window resolutions? a 1024x1024 window should look exactly like a 512x512 window? or it should be the 1/4 part of it?

Comment: You should show us some more code (e.g. where you're drawing in C++). This sounds a bit like there's some issue with how you're drawing things or how your window's view is set up.

Comment: @dv1729 I edited the post to make it clearer.

Mario, my code is only drawing sprites on the screen, there is nothing extraordinary, the only problem is that I don't handle resizing event so SFML does the job alone, but doesn't tells the shader the window is resized.

Comment: can you post the pics with some minimum light everywhere?

Comment: @dv1729 done ! is it better ?

Comment: I just think that you have problems with the different coordinates, keep in mind that OpenGL sets the origin of coordinates on the lower-left part of the window (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml)

Comment: Does resizing somehow move the drawing offset for any elements? That would explain that. You should add the code where you're actually using the shader (can probably be shortened/simplified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The code snippet you're showing really only updates the shader coordinates (and from a quick glimpse it looks fine). The bug most likely happens somewhere where you're actually drawing things.*

---

I'd use a completely different approach, because your shader approach might get rather tedious once you're rendering multiple things, other light sources, etc.

As such I'd suggest you render a light map to a render texture (which would essentially be like "black = no light, color = light of that color").

Rather than trying to explain everything in text, I've written a quick commented example program which will draw a window on screen and move some light sources over a background image (I've used the one that comes with SFML's shader example):

[image: Screenshot of the example code in action]

There are no requirements other than having a file called "background.jpg" in your startup path.

Feel free to copy this code or use it for inspiration. Just keep in mind this isn't optimized and really just a quick edit to show the general idea.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

const float PI = 3.1415f;

struct Light
{
    sf::Vector2f position;
    sf::Color color;
    float radius;
};

int main()
{
    // Let's setup a window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Lights");
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(false);
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    // Create something simple to draw
    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile("background.jpg");
    sf::Sprite background(texture);

    // Setup everything for the lightmap
    sf::RenderTexture lightmapTex;
    // We're using a 512x512 render texture for max. compatibility
    // On modern hardware it could match the window resolution of course
    lightmapTex.create(512, 512);
    sf::Sprite lightmap(lightmapTex.getTexture());
    // Scale the sprite to fill the window
    lightmap.setScale(640 / 512.f, 480 / 512.f);
    // Set the lightmap's view to the same as the window
    lightmapTex.setView(window.getDefaultView());

    // Drawable helper to draw lights
    // We'll just have to adjust the first vertex's color to tint it
    sf::VertexArray light(sf::PrimitiveType::TriangleFan);
    light.append({sf::Vector2f(0, 0), sf::Color::White});
    // This is inaccurate, but for demo purposes…
    // This could be more elaborate to allow better graduation etc.
    for (float i = 0; i  <= 2 * PI; i += PI * .125f)
        light.append({sf::Vector2f(std::sin(i), std::cos(i)), sf::Color::Transparent});

    // Setup some lights
    std::vector<Light> lights;
    lights.push_back({sf::Vector2f(50.f, 50.f), sf::Color::White, 100.f });
    lights.push_back({sf::Vector2f(350.f, 150.f), sf::Color::Red, 150.f });
    lights.push_back({sf::Vector2f(150.f, 250.f), sf::Color::Yellow, 200.f });
    lights.push_back({sf::Vector2f(250.f, 450.f), sf::Color::Cyan, 100.f });

    // RenderStates helper to transform and draw lights
    sf::RenderStates rs(sf::BlendAdd);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
            }
        }

        bool flip = false; // simple toggle to animate differently

        // Draw the light map
        lightmapTex.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        for(Light &l : lights)
        {
            // Apply all light attributes and render it

            // Reset the transformation
            rs.transform = sf::Transform::Identity;

            // Move the light
            rs.transform.translate(l.position);

            // And scale it (this could be animated to create flicker)
            rs.transform.scale(l.radius, l.radius);

            // Adjust the light color (first vertex)
            light[0].color = l.color;

            // Draw the light
            lightmapTex.draw(light, rs);

            // To make things a bit more interesting
            // We're moving the lights
            l.position.x += flip ? 2 : -2;
            flip = !flip;
            if (l.position.x > 640)
                l.position.x -= 640;
            else if (l.position.x < 0)
                l.position.x += 640;
        }
        lightmapTex.display();

        window.clear(sf::Color::White);
        // Draw the background / game
        window.draw(background);
        // Draw the lightmap
        window.draw(lightmap, sf::BlendMultiply);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow I wasn't prepared for that xD Seems pretty cool, I'm gonna try this out, thanks !

Comment: @FeelZoR Just in case I wasn't clear, you can draw lights in any shape, so it's pretty trivial to draw spotlights or any other non-circular light sources.